# Check if student submitted assignment via Moodle web services

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to use the Moodle API (web services) to get information about (my) assignment submissions. I want to know whether I submitted an attempt for the assignment already or not. I am using the `mod_assign_get_assignments` function (which doesn't have too much documentation) and the results I get (when looking at the `assignments` portion of each course) are:

```
{
  "id": 25960,
  "cmid": 350053,
  "course": 8013502,
  "name": "\u05d4\u05d2\u05e9\u05ea \u05ea\u05e8\u05d2\u05d9\u05dc \u05d1\u05d9\u05ea 1",
  "nosubmissions": 0,
  "submissiondrafts": 0,
  "sendnotifications": 0,
  "sendlatenotifications": 0,
  "sendstudentnotifications": 0,
  "duedate": 1617566400,
  "allowsubmissionsfromdate": 0,
  "grade": 100,
  "timemodified": 1615897679,
  "completionsubmit": 1,
  "cutoffdate": 1617569940,
  "gradingduedate": 0,
  "teamsubmission": 0,
  "requireallteammemberssubmit": 0,
  "teamsubmissiongroupingid": 0,
  "blindmarking": 0,
  "hidegrader": 0,
  "revealidentities": 0,
  "attemptreopenmethod": "manual",
  "maxattempts": 1,
  "markingworkflow": 0,
  "markingallocation": 0,
  "requiresubmissionstatement": 0,
  "preventsubmissionnotingroup": 0
   ...irrelevant configuations
}
```

The above result is for an assignment I have already submitted.

An example of an assignment I did not submit is:

```
{
  "id": 19764,
  "cmid": 268225,
  "course": 8013201,
  "name": "\u05ea\u05d9\u05d1\u05ea \u05d4\u05d2\u05e9\u05d4 14",
  "nosubmissions": 0,
  "submissiondrafts": 0,
  "sendnotifications": 0,
  "sendlatenotifications": 0,
  "sendstudentnotifications": 0,
  "duedate": 1611693000,
  "allowsubmissionsfromdate": 0,
  "grade": 100,
  "timemodified": 1610972842,
  "completionsubmit": 0,
  "cutoffdate": 1611694860,
  "gradingduedate": 0,
  "teamsubmission": 0,
  "requireallteammemberssubmit": 0,
  "teamsubmissiongroupingid": 0,
  "blindmarking": 0,
  "hidegrader": 0,
  "revealidentities": 0,
  "attemptreopenmethod": "manual",
  "maxattempts": 1,
  "markingworkflow": 0,
  "markingallocation": 0,
  "requiresubmissionstatement": 0,
  "preventsubmissionnotingroup": 0
   ...irrelevant configuations
}
```

The only apparent difference between these (that might point to a way to check if I submitted it or not) is the `completionsubmit` property, but that cannot be the solution because a different assignment that I have submitted has it set to 0 (just like the one I didn't submit).

Does someone have an idea how I can solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT:** `mod_assign_get_submissions` denies my access

`{"assignments":[],"warnings":[{"item":"assignment","itemid":myitemname,"warningcode":"1","message":"No access rights in module context"}]}`

I looked now into `mod_assign_get_submission_status` but it seems like it is only able to parse one assignment at a time, does anyone have a way to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `mod_assign_get_submissions` instead to retrieve submissions to assignments. Available since Moodle 2.5

#### References

- [Moodle API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions)
- [Emulated Data For Get Submissions from Moodle](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile/blob/master/emulator/mod_assign_get_submissions.json)

#### Sample Response

```json
{
    "assignments": [
        {
            "assignmentid": 14,
            "submissions": [
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "userid": 3,
                    "attemptnumber": 0,
                    "timecreated": 1426865031,
                    "timemodified": 1426865062,
                    "status": "submitted",
                    "groupid": 0,
                    "plugins": [
                        {
                            "type": "onlinetext",
                            "name": "Online text",
                            "fileareas": [
                                {
                                    "area": "submissions_onlinetext"
                                }
                            ],
                            "editorfields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "onlinetext",
                                    "description": "Submission comments",
                                    "text": "<p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful.&nbsp;<br></p>",
                                    "format": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "file",
                            "name": "File submissions",
                            "fileareas": [
                                {
                                    "area": "submission_files",
                                    "files": [
                                        {
                                            "filepath": "APDFfile.pdf",
                                            "fileurl": "http://localhost/m/stable_master/webservice/pluginfile.php/247/assignsubmission_file/submission_files/12/somefile.pdf"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "filepath": "anotherfile.docx",
                                            "fileurl": "http://localhost/m/stable_master/webservice/pluginfile.php/247/assignsubmission_file/submission_files/12/somefile.pdf"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "comments",
                            "name": "Submission comments"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "userid": 4,
                    "attemptnumber": 0,
                    "timecreated": 1426864693,
                    "timemodified": 1426864740,
                    "status": "draft",
                    "groupid": 0,
                    "plugins": [
                        {
                            "type": "onlinetext",
                            "name": "Online text",
                            "fileareas": [
                                {
                                    "area": "submissions_onlinetext",
                                    "files": [
                                        {
                                            "filepath": "/Arte esquemático-Cigüeña.png",
                                            "fileurl": "http://localhost/m/stable_master/webservice/pluginfile.php/245/assignsubmission_onlinetext/submissions_onlinetext/5/Arte%20esquem%C3%A1tico-Cig%C3%BCe%C3%B1a.png"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "editorfields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "onlinetext",
                                    "description": "Submission comments",
                                    "text": "<p>Blah Blah Blah lorem ipsum</p><p><br></p><p><b>Blah Blah Blah lorem ipsum</b><br></p><p><b><br></b></p><p><b><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\"><i>Blah Blah Blah lorem ipsum</i></span><br></b></p><p><b><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\"><i><br></i></span></b></p><p><b><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\"><i><img src=\"@@PLUGINFILE@@/Arte%20esquem%C3%A1tico-Cig%C3%BCe%C3%B1a.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"734\" height=\"844\" role=\"presentation\" style=\"vertical-align:text-bottom; margin: 0 .5em;\" class=\"img-responsive\"><br></i></span></b></p>",
                                    "format": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "file",
                            "name": "File submissions",
                            "fileareas": [
                                {
                                    "area": "submission_files",
                                    "files": [
                                        {
                                            "filepath": "somefile.pdf",
                                            "fileurl": "http://localhost/m/stable_master/webservice/pluginfile.php/247/assignsubmission_file/submission_files/12/somefile.pdf"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "comments",
                            "name": "Submission comments"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "warnings": []
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried your method, see my edited question for further details :)